# Formatting exponents in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, number-formatting

I have a numbers like 1.0e-4, 1.0e-10, 1.5e-12. I want to write these number to a file discarding numbers after decimal like 1e-4, 1e-10, 1e-12. %g seems to do trick for second number but it has limitation of exponents greater than 5. I want to have 1e+00 even for 1.0. I'm getting 1.000000e-04 for 1.0e-4 with %e and str().

Comment: So your changing 1.0 to 1e+00 or the other way round?

Comment: but `1.5e` will be rounded to `2e`

Comment: Try `"%.0e" % n`. For your reference, 1.5e-12 is 2e-12, not 1e-12.

Comment: split() with a list comprehension to get the character before the decimal and the character after the 'e'? Is there a need to do the work before converting to a string?

Comment: @DYZ I wanted to discard .5 in case of 1.5e-12 to make it 1e-12.

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld 1.0 to 1e+00.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've found a temporary solution with regex. Matched with "([0-9])\.[0-9]+(e.*)?" and appended group 1 and group 3.

Comment: @dg_no_9 I have edited my question with something that will work for any number of exponents

Comment: @dg_no_9 I have edited it again. See the **Edit:** section, it will now print as you want

Comment: @dg_no_9 No idea why, I will look at this in the morning. Glad to hear that I have helped :) Just don't forget to up vote and mark as the answer! Lol

Comment: @DYZ Your answer seems to do the trick. Only interesting thing is "%.0e"%1.5e-12 gives 2e-12 where as "%.0e"%1.5e-10 gives 1e-10. Any idea why? Eitherway, this solves my problem though. Thanks a lot. I was replying to wrong person, my bad!

Comment: Most floating point numbers in Python are approximate. 1.5e-10 must be approximated by a number that is smaller than the actual arithmetic 1.5e-10.

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1 (Doesn't work with exponents smaller than 5):

Use `"%.0g" % 1.5e-12`

If you want to change `1.5e-12` you can always use a variable in its place

`"%.0g" % 1.5e-12` Gives an output of `'2e-12'`

`"%.0g" % 1.0e-4` Gives an output of `'0.0001'`

## Method 2 (Works with any number of exponents):

To be able to use any number of exponents, use:

```
from decimal import *
'%.1e' % Decimal("%.0g" % 1.5e-12)
```

Using this code:

`'%.1e' % Decimal("%.0g" % 1.5e-12)` Gives an output of `'2.0e-12'`

`'%.1e' % Decimal("%.0g" % 1.0e-4)` Gives an output of `'1.0e-04'`

**Edit:**

Use:

```
from decimal import *
'%.0e' % Decimal("%.0g" % 1.5e-12)
```

For `2e-12` rather than `2.0e-12`

Comment: @dg_no_9 If this was the answer you were looking for, make sure to mark it as the answer and upvote, It helps a lot! :)